# There is no active component instance at vue 2.7

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue 2.6.14 + composition-api 1.6.2

I want to upgrade the app as vue 2.7 (surely, remove composition-api)

I am using two repositories,
one is the main and the other is UMD library.
(both use vue, vue-cli)

The problem is, it looks like there is no active instance at UMD library.
Please look below codes

```js
// repo B(the UMD library) > someComponent.vue
<template>
   ...
</template>
<script>
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'; 

export default {
   ...
   setup() {
       const vm = getCurrentInstance();
       console.log(vm);    // <- null
       ...
       onMounted(...);  // <- [Vue warn] onMounted is called when there is no active component instance to be associated with. Lifecycle injection APIs can only be used during execution of setup().
   }
}
```

```js
// repo A(the main) > somePage.vue
<template>
   ...
   <someComponent>...</someComponent>
</template>
<script>
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue';
import { someComponent } from '@some-company/design-system'; 
...
export default {
    ...
    components: {
        someComponent
    },
    setup() {
        const vm = getCurrentInstance();
        console.log(vm);    // <- VueComponent (It works well!)
        ... 
        onMounted(...); // No warning has logged (It works well!)
    }
}
```

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62732556/currentinstance-value-is-null-for-the-bundled-component

Comment: Found the solution at GitHub
https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/1503